# Sanitising data for a flutter application

Tags: xss, android, databases, encoding, validation

I am having trouble with some user input security. I have a Flutter app where users can submit comments that can contain text e.g. a-z characters, numbers, symbols and emojis. These are stored in a Firestore database.

I have performed checks to ensure the type of the comment is a string and not over a maximum size but I feel this is not enough.

Are there an security vulnerabilities with storing this data in the database and simply relaying it on the users Android/iOS device? I have read about XSS but I am no expert and I am not sure if this is applicable with compiled APKs/IPAs.

I have also read about encoding the data but I don't see much benefit to this if I will just convert it back (also couldn't find a method to convert it back in Flutter, I was using the escape method in Node to convert it).

If somebody could help explain more on this topic, as everything I search comes up with browser based HTML answers, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Does Flutter interpret HTML? Additionally, if you are storing this information in a database, your main worry is going to be SQL injection.

Comment: It compiles to java/swift to the best of my knowledge. The database is nosql so sql injection shouldn't be a problem. I do allow users to upload images/videos, could anything malicious be done with that?

Comment: Well, there are some mobile frameworks (e.g. Cordova, Phonegap) that use and render HTML and JavaScript, so of course web vulnerabilities apply in those cases. I do not know what Flutter does though. I also don't think using nosql gives you a pass against injection there either